# Thymeleaf Double Reference to CSS

Tags: css, thymeleaf

In many Thymeleaf examples (such as [a Spring Boot Thymeleaf example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-ui/src/main/resources/templates/layout.html), links to stylesheets are referenced twice in the link where the first reference uses the Thymeleaf `th:ref` and the second uses a standard `href`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
    th:href="@/css/bootstrap.min.css}"
    href="../../css/bootstrap.min.css"
 />
```

Removing the `href="../../css/bootstrap.min.css"` does not seem to break anything.

Is there any benefit to having the double reference or could something go wrong if the second reference is removed?

Comment: It might be a redundant fallback to the `th:href`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for the second `href` as explained in the [documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls):

> The th:href tag allowed us to (**optionally**) have a working static href
>   attribute in our template, so that our template links remained
>   navigable by a browser when opened directly for prototyping purposes.

So the benefit of having the static reference is to have a working template and navigable using a browser, the best case for prototyping. But if you want to remove it, nothing goes wrong.